# Computing text similarity against many documents

Tags: python, information-retrieval, cosine-similarity, document-classification

I'm trying to compute the text similarity of a search term, **A**, like "How to make chickens" against a collection of other search terms. To compute similarity I'm using the cosine distance and TF-IDF to transform **A** into a vector. I'd like to compare the similarity of **A** against *all* documents at once.

Currently, my approach involves computing the cosine similarity for **A** against every other document one at a time, iteratively. I have 100 documents I'm comparing against. If the result of `cos_sim(A, X) > 0.8` then I break and say "cool, this is similar".

However, I feel like this might not be a true representation of the overall similarity. Is there a way to pre-compute a vector(s) for my 100 documents at runtime, and every time I see a new search query **A**, I can compare against this pre-defined vector/document?

I believe I can achieve this by simply combining all documents into one... feels rough though. What are the pros and & cons, and possible solutions? Extra points for efficiency!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is essentially the traditional search problem: Have you tried putting your documents into something like [Lucene (Java)](https://lucene.apache.org/) or [Whoosh (python)](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html)? I think they have a cosine-similarity model (but even if they don't, the default may be better).

The general trick all search engines use is that in general, documents are sparse. This means to compute the similarity (e.g., cosine similarity) it only matters what the lengths of the documents are (known way ahead of time) and the ***terms that they both contain***; you can organize a data structure like a back-of-the-book index, called an [inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) that can quickly tell you which documents will get at least a non-zero score.

With only 100 documents, a search engine is probably overkill; you want to pre-compute the TF-IDF vectors and keep them in a numpy matrix. You can then use numpy operations to compute the dot product all at once for all the documents -- it will output a 1x100 vector of the [numerators you need](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Definition). The denominators can similarly be precomputed. A `numpy.max(numpy.dot(query, docs)/denom)` will then probably be fast enough.

You should profile your code, but I would bet your vector extraction is the slow part; but you should only have to do that once for all queries.

If you had thousands or millions of documents to compare against, you could look into SciKit learn's K-nearest-neighbor structures (e.g., [Ball Tree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.BallTree) or [KDTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.KDTree), or things like [Facebook's FAISS library](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss).